# visual studio .vcxproj changes to generate exe

Tags: c++, visual-c++, compilation, vcxproj

In my project there are multiple subdirectories, out of which one is utils,
and utils.vcxproj has details like below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="14.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup Label="ProjectConfigurations">
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|x64">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|x64">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>x64</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="Globals">
    <ProjectGuid>{1705D35F-B357-4C31-A45C-D18AD75D9325}</ProjectGuid>
    <Keyword>Win32Proj</Keyword>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'" Label="Configuration">
    <PlatformToolset>v140</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets">
    <Import Project="$(SolutionDir)PABuildConfig_StaticLibrary.props" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionSettings">
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Debug|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <ImportGroup Label="PropertySheets" Condition="'$(Configuration)|$(Platform)'=='Release|x64'">
    <Import Project="$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props" Condition="exists('$(UserRootDir)\Microsoft.Cpp.$(Platform).user.props')" Label="LocalAppDataPlatform" />
  </ImportGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Label="UserMacros" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="case.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="checksum.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="codeword.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="convdate.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="dbm_log.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="escape.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="exparamutil.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="filelist.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="filelist_win32.cpp" />
    <ClCompile Include="file_get.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="get_time.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="hooklist.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="list.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="ntharg.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="nthline.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="search.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="set.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="stradd.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="strlist.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="strtrim.c" />
    <ClCompile Include="tail.c" />

  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="convdate.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="dbm_log.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="filelist.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="hooklist.h" />
    <ClInclude Include="list.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.targets" />
  <ImportGroup Label="ExtensionTargets">
  </ImportGroup>
  

</Project>
```

Output of compilation is utils.lib

Now I wanted to add one more extra file say cvalidate.c in same subdirectory, but this should not be part of utils.lib and post compile, it should generate cvalidate.exe

I was able to achieve this on Linux platform, where I successfully generated executable cvalidate by adding changes in makefiles, but I am new to Windows concepts of Visual studio .vcxproj file.

So wanted to know what changes should I add in utils.vcxproj file.
I added entry like below but it did not served the purpose:

```
   <ClCompile Include="cvalidate.c">
        <ExcludedFromBuild>false</ExcludedFromBuild>
    </ClCompile>
    <Link Include="cvalidate.c">
        <SubSystem>Console</SubSystem>
        <OutputFile>cvalidate.exe</OutputFile>
        <AdditionalDependencies>utils.lib</AdditionalDependencies>
    </Link>
```

Comment: I would not mess around with the project files directly. I don't believe they are formally documented (could be wrong). VS has a post build step in the IDE. That's probably where you should be looking to add the extra build actions you want. Also the file that you want to add can be marked as excluded from the build so that it doesn't end up in the library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to create another project (vcxproj) in the same solution (sln).
Each project build one binary, you can also specify dependencies between project of the same solution.

Comment: Thanks @M'hand BOUGHIAS, let me try